# Modal popup moves on high resolution monitor

Tags: css

I have AJAX modal pop up on my web page and altered to scroll with page.

Everything is ok in simple monitors.
But in high resolution monitors when i select any item from dropdown on modal it moves.

the dropdown has not postback even

Modal is scrollable so its X and Y is 0

Answer (score 0):

try fixed Height and width value